# Route base/id to controller/action/id in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to redirect users when they enter a URL into the browser based on the ID. For example, a user enters:

```
http://localhost:50431/10213
```

and they will be redirected to:

```
http://localhost:50431/home/job/10213
```

**Default Route:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{jobno}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Job", jobno = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Job Number",
  url: "{jobno}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Job" },
  new { jobno = @"[0-9]*" }      
);
```

And put it above the other route. The added parameter is to avoid the route catching urls like `http://localhost:50431/foobar`, but only the ones that contain numbers.

Please note I don't have a way of testing this at the moment so you may have to tweak it slightly.

Comment: Yeah I've tweaked it and it now works. Thanks! Here's what I changed: `routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Job Number",
              url: "{jobno}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Job", jobno = new { jobno = @"[0-9]*" } }
            );`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Job Number",
  url: "{jobno}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Job", .jobno = UrlParameter.Optional },
  constraints: new { jobno = @"[0-9]*" }      
);
```

I have tested this and it works properly, his reply in the comment did not work properly  for me.